# Editing configuration files in AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

Where i can find the configuration files for AWS EMR? Mainly I am looking for hue.ini file, I launched a new cluster, opened hue UI, created new super user and logged in. Then i see all my s3 buckets in that region, but i am not able access the files in the bucket, I keep getting this error -

```
Failed to access path: "s3a://data-storage" Check that you have access to read this bucket and that the region is correct: Bad Request.
```

Then i tried to add my s3 account to hue as per this  - http://gethue.com/introducing-s3-support-in-hue/ . As per this AWS link - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html, I am trying to add it in the configurations in my cluster.

1. As per the above AWS link, they say i have to add it only when i create the cluster, cant we add in an existing cluster? If so, where i can add it?
2. How can i add the s3 configuration in Hue and hadoop with s3 in AWS configurations? Any example will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> they say i have to add it only when i create the cluster

Yes, because if you plan on turning off the EMR cluster, and it bootstraps a separate machine on next boot, then you'll lose the config. There is an "advanced options" section of the cluster setup where you specify a configuration JSON object.

EMR Hue is automatically configured to read S3, assuming the IAM roles allow it to do so, but you're welcome to edit the hue.ini after the cluster is started

```
/usr/lib/hue/desktop/conf/hue.ini
```

After editing,

```
sudo reload hue
```